# MongoDB Bulk Write Not Updating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

From what I see in the docs I'm doing this correctly, but I don't know why it's not updating the document. http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite

```
const updates = [
{
  "updateOne": {
    "filter": {
      "Item": {
        "$oid": "59bdbf4f857c5b78b3a4c400"
      },
      "Path": "ShortDescription"
    },
    "update": {
      "$set": {
        "Value": "100 knotzzzz"
      }
    }
  }
}
]

await mongoose.connection.db.collection('productdata').bulkWrite(updates);
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you found solution for this?

Comment: I was having the same issue, my problem was that i was using as filter `"filter":{"_id":"61c84d2387fc71031f3e6ca3"}` instead of `{"_id":ObjectId("61c84d2387fc71031f3e6ca3")}`

Answer (score 1):

I am using the `initializeUnorderedBulkOp` method and it's working, but I'd still like to know why bulk write didn't work. Here is the code that is working for me.

```
  const bulk = mongoose.connection.db.collection('productdatas').initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

  data.forEach(([Path, Value]) => {
    bulk.find({ Item: new ObjectID(_id), Path }).updateOne({
      $set: {
        Value,
      },
    });
  });

  await bulk.execute();
```

Comment: It did not work because `"Item": {  "$oid": "59bdbf4f857c5b78b3a4c400"  }` is not actually valid. You instead cast to `ObjectId` as you have done. Note that using [`.bulkWrite()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite) as a "mongoose method" will actually do "autocasting" based on the schema when you do: `"Item": "59bdbf4f857c5b78b3a4c400"` as long as the actual schema for `Item` is set as `Item: Schema.Types.ObjectId`. If it is not set to the correct type, then autocasting fails.

Comment: Also, You should **always** check the result of the method. And it should show `nMatched` as 0 due to incorrect query values, which should give you a pretty clear hint.